# Bluetooth Randomly Stopped

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I'm using a Developer, Ubuntu shipped with it pre-installed Dell Precision 7530. Today while working, my bluetooth speakers beeped indicating they disconnected, I went to reconnect and in the bluetooth settings it's saying "No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth." - except I've been using bluetooth for the entire 6 months I've owned the laptop so there absolutely is a dongle. I've restarted the computer several times, including fully off/on, and nothing. I'm at a loss. Any suggestions here?

I've seen other chats about bluetooth not working but they tend to be people that upgraded recently etc. - I haven't. It just STOPPED after working fine and flawlessly.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you sure you did not disable it via some keyboard combination? 

Comment: I have the laptop connected to an external monitor and usb wireless keyboard... lid is shut most of the time so I don't see how I could have - but who knows anything is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://memcpy.io/fixing-bluetooth-on-the-xps-15-9550-on-ubuntu.html)

Upgrade BIOS using a flash drive (after downloading it from official DELL drivers website link)

**Note:-** This could be BIOS issue too but not 100% sure

```
wget https://memcpy.io/files/2017-10-28/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd

sudo cp BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/

sudo chmod 0644 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd

sudo reboot
```

Comment: Good idea, however it didn't solve the issue. Appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: I stand corrected - upon rebooting my bios flashed the update, and now my bluetooth is working. Well done Sachin!!